# Facing this issue while redirect google OAuth in Laravel 9 "Object of class Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException could not be converted to int"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

While I authorize my account in this `user()` function throws the error.
Help me to find out the solution.

```php
public function callback()
{
        try {

            $google_user = Socialite::driver('google')->user(); //Here I got error
            $user = user::where('email', $google_user->email)->first();
            if ($user) {
                Auth::login($user);
                return redirect('user');
            } else {
                $new_user = User::create([
                    'name' => ucwords($google_user->name),
                    'email' => $google_user->email,
                    'email_verified_at' => now(),
                    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
                    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
                ]);
                Auth::login($user);
                return redirect('user');
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            abort($th);
        }
}
```

Comment: `abort` takes 2 parameters, the first being the http response code

Answer (score 0):

**you have an error User not user ex :**

```
 $user = User::where('email',$google_user->email)->first();
```

i hope it was useful